# what could be the error in this isset login html / php form

Tags: php, html, isset

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $username = $_POST['namea'];
             echo " hello {$_POST['namea']}";

 }


?> <form method = "post" action = "">
<input type = "text" name = "namea"/>
<input type = "password" name = "pass"/>
<input type = "submit" name = "Login"/>
</form>
```

i want it to display my name on the browser after i click login button, instead of getting the name its displaying nothing on my side what could be the error here

Comment: If someone called you by another "name", would you answer? There you go; same thing goes for inputs being wrong name attribute ;-)

Comment: i have used 'name = "namea" an am trying to access it here {$_POST['namea']}

Comment: "submit" is also an "input" :-)

Comment: Use error reporting and you will see the error.